# Adding legend for geom_line to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm generating a chart line graph with ggplot, the main purpose of the graph it to display some sample values over time for some points(the number of points can vary, there is one line for each point). There is also a line I added to show if the values exceed a predefined limit.
I get a legend on the right that map each point, but I didn't manage to add a legend for the limit.
Here is the code that generate the graph :

```
library(ggplot2)
df2 <- subset(dataset, ResultNumericValue < 1000000)
names(df2)[4] <- "PointName"
df2[[1]] <- as.POSIXct(df2[[1]], tz="GMT", format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")
ggplot(df2, aes(x=SampleDate, y=ResultNumericValue)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=PointName)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=PointName))+
  geom_line(aes(y = UpperLimit, color=UpperLimit), color="red", size=1) +
  labs(x = "Sample Date", y = "Sample Value", color="Points") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "darkgrey", size = 0.5, linetype = 3),
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50"))
```

The looks like this :

```
                SampleDate           ResultNumericValue  UpperLimit    point name
1 2020-03-03T16:00:00.0000000                  4         13            1
2 2020-03-05T16:00:00.0000000                  1         13            1
3 2020-03-23T07:30:48.2870000                  2         13            1
4 2020-03-24T00:07:43.6030000                  1         13            CW1
5 2020-03-24T06:56:41.1170000                  2         13            CW1
```

And this is what the graph look like :
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltz1C.png)

I just would like to add something to explain that the red horizontal line is the upper limit.
I tried to use the scale_discrete_manual but it changes the sites legend.
What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to deal with this is to use a `geom_hline` for the upper limit. If you map its linetype to the string `'Upper Limit'` it will have its own separate entry in the legend.

```r
ggplot(df2, aes(SampleDate, ResultNumericValue, color = PointName)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 13, linetype = 'Upper Limit'), color = "red", 
             size = 1) +
  labs(x = "Sample Date", y = "Sample Value", 
       color = "Points", linetype = NULL) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "darkgrey", 
                                        size = 0.5, linetype = 3),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works !
Any chance you could explain why the geom_hline generate a 2nd legend while the geom_line doesn't ?

Comment: @LePhasme the second legend is actually a legend for the line type, but it only has a single line type. Because we have only mapped line type inside geom_hline, it takes the color we have given to the geom_hline

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you passed the color as an argument. If you want to have your line displayed in the legend you have to map on the `color` aes. To this end map a constant value e.g. `"UpperLimit"` on the color aes and set your desired colors via `scale_color_manual`. Additionally I used the `override.aes` argument of `guide_legend` to remove the points from the legend keys for the upper limit line:

```r
library(ggplot2)
df2 <- subset(dataset, ResultNumericValue < 1000000)
names(df2)[4] <- "PointName"
df2[[1]] <- as.POSIXct(df2[[1]], tz = "GMT", format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")
ggplot(df2, aes(x = SampleDate, y = ResultNumericValue)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = PointName)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = PointName)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = UpperLimit, color = "UpperLimit"), size = 1) +
  labs(x = "Sample Date", y = "Sample Value", color = "Points") +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "darkgrey", size = 0.5, linetype = 3),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50")
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("1" = "blue", CW1 = "green", UpperLimit = "red")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(16, 16, NA))))
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
dataset <- structure(list(
  SampleDate = c(
    "2020-03-03T16:00:00.0000000",
    "2020-03-05T16:00:00.0000000", "2020-03-23T07:30:48.2870000",
    "2020-03-24T00:07:43.6030000", "2020-03-24T06:56:41.1170000"
  ),
  ResultNumericValue = c(4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), UpperLimit = c(
    13L,
    13L, 13L, 13L, 13L
  ), point.name = c(
    "1", "1", "1", "CW1",
    "CW1"
  )
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  "1", "2", "3",
  "4", "5"
))
```